# Subscribe a channel only if a key exists in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe, atomic

In my nodejs app, I'm using Redis keys as channel names. I want a client to subscribe a channel only if the corresponding key exists. The problem is between a EXISTS command and a SUBSCRIBE command, another client may remove an existing key. I can't use WATCH-MULTI-EXEC to make it atomic because I can't use SUBSCRIBE within a MULTI-EXEC block. I can't use Lua script either.

If there any way to maintain atomicity in this case?

Comment: what should happen if a key is removed after clients have subscribed?

Comment: It will publish an `unsubscribe` message to the channel, a client should  unsubscribe when receiving an `unsubscribe` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible with current version of Redis. I switched to a different approach that do not require atomic subscribe.